# No virtual method addReactInstanceEventListener when running detox in release

Tags: android, detox

I am using detox to test a react-native app.

iOS tests are working and android tests are also working when using -DtestBuildType=debug

Now I am trying to get -DtestBuildType=release working since I want to test it on bitrise and I don't have success in using debug mode for that.

I created a emulator which is working for debug in Android studio. 
The package.json config for release is as following:

```
"android.emu.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
    "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
    "type": "android.emulator",
    "name": "Nexus_5X_API_26"
  },
  "android.emu.release": {
    "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
    "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..",
    "type": "android.emulator",
    "name": "Nexus_5X_API_26"
  }
```

When running `detox test -c android.emu.release --loglevel trace` detox fails with `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 120000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.`

and trace shows us

```
detox[16787] DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=testee not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=ff9d0ed4-d98e-c4ff-397c-9b32e357247a)
```

and

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method addReactInstanceEventListener(Lcom/facebook/react/ReactInstanceManager$ReactInstanceEventListener;)V in class Lcom/facebook/react/ReactInstanceManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager' appears in /data/app/com.XXXX/base.apk)
    at com.wix.detox.ReactNativeSupport$2.run(Unknown Source:28)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:2092)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Is there something missing when building the release apk which prevents detox from connecting properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this is related to Proguard/R8/minification. When I set `minifyEnabled` to `false`, this problem goes away for me. If I get this working, I'll try to put together a proper answer.

Comment: I've tried adding minifyEnabled false, but an issue still persists.
`TRACE: [DetoxServer.js/MESSAGE] role=tester action=invoke (sessionId=ef44f77e-9da4-4405-ccf8-4025c85af5cb)

DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/CANNOT_FORWARD] role=app not connected, cannot fw action (sessionId=ef44f77e-9da4-4405-ccf8-4025c85af5cb) `